# Maven build in Jenkins failing : mvn: command not found

Tags: linux, maven, jenkins, command-line, build

I have installed Jenkins and Maven separately in my Linux server. Maven is working from prompt. I tested by giving mvn -version and it gave below output:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.5 
Maven home: /data1/SOA/app/oracle/product/middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.maven_3.2.5
Java version: 1.8.0_151, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /data1/setup_files/JDK1.8/jdk1.8.0_151/jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.8.13-55.1.6.el7uek.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

But from Jenkins when I try to give a maven build from Jenkins with below shell script:

```
export M2_HOME=/data1/SOA/app/oracle/product/middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.maven_3.2.5
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
echo "Java Version"
java -version
echo "Maven Version"
mvn -version
```

It throws following error:

```
+ echo 'Java Version'
Java Version
+ java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
+ echo 'Maven Version'
Maven Version
+ mvn -version
/tmp/jenkins6612268406133694375.sh: line 7: mvn: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

I gone through several links and blogs, but none of the steps are helping. I have done the following:

In Manage Jenkins --> Configuration --> Environment variables --> set JAVA_HOME, M2_HOME, ORACLE_HOME, PATH

In Manage Jenkins --> Global Tool Configuration --> set JAVA_HOME and MAVEN_HOME to installation directory in server

I also restarted Jenkins and checked, but still same issue.

Comment: I would look into the PATH configuration of your Jenkins installation. Compare this to the PATH value in your own shell. I guess that the installation path of maven is only in your shell PATH variable.

Comment: This is how I did the PATH configuration in Jenkins.  From shell I ran echo $PATH and the value I got , I pasted in PATH configuration of Jenkins installation at: Manage Jenkins --> Configuration --> Environment variables -->Path.

Comment: In Jenkins you have a part Global Tool Configuration where you should define the tools you have available and not via Path of the Machine on wich Jenkins is running...

Comment: I have already added the Maven installation path in Global Tool Configuration but still getting mvn not found error. But There is a warning in yellow appearing under Global Tool Configuration --> Maven Installation ---> MAVEN_HOME. The warning is /data1/SOA/app/oracle/product/middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.maven_3.2.5 is not a directory on the Jenkins master (but perhaps it exists on some agents)

Comment: Could you try to run a “which mvn” in your own shell? That could tell you if your $PATH append in the script above actually points to the mvn executable. Do you know if you have multiple maven installations on the host?

Comment: I ran which mvn and this is the output: /data1/SOA/app/oracle/product/middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.maven_3.2.5/bin/mvn

Answer (score 4):

are you using a Jenkinsfile for your pipeline? 
If so try adding the following part to your pipeline script:

```
    tools {
        maven 'Maven 3.2.5'
    }
```

Thats doing to the trick in our project

Comment: I am not using Jenkinsfile. I have created a freestyle project and in build --> execute shell , i am giving the maven commands. In my local system which is windows the Jenkins and Maven setup was working fine. After which I installed the jenkins in our server which is linux. In Linux it is failing .

Comment: can you check in your jenkins if you have maven setup correctly under jenkins/manage jenkins/global tool configuration?

Comment: under jenkins/manage jenkins/global tool configuration , under maven I have added as following : [1] Name = org.apache.maven_3.2.5                                      
     [2] MAVEN_HOME = /data1/SOA/app/oracle/product/middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.maven_3.2.5                ................................... This path I got by doing echo $M2_HOME from the shell.

Comment: I checked under Manage Jenkins ---> Manage Nodes --> master . In script console I ran println System.getenv("M2_HOME") and output is null. From server (linux) cmd , all variables are coming (echo $var)......Does this indicate anything?

Answer (score 2):

The execute shell does not know about the Maven settings; only the maven job type or step does.

Assuming Jenkins 2.x,
Under Jenkins | Manage Jenkins | Global Tool Configuration, 
there's a section called "Maven" - Maven installations

click "Add Maven"

Name: "Maven-3.2.5"
MAVEN_HOME:/data1/SOA/app/oracle/product/middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.maven_3.2.5

Your freestyle job should then have an "Invoke top-level Maven targets" step.

Set "Maven Version": "Maven-3.2.5".

You can have shell steps prior to and after to deal with any non-maven steps in your job.

Comment: I did as per your steps, but now I am getting this error: Couldn’t find any executable in /data1/SOA/app/oracle/product/middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.maven_3.2.5
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure

Comment: I took that to be where you said you installed maven (although I'd install into it's own directory, not inside oracle_common), so I don't know. Is the maven binary there? It should be at ${MAVEN_HOME}/bin/mvn. Try downloading from http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi and untaring to a known location. Then set MAVEN_HOME accordingly.

Comment: The tip to use "Invoke top-level Maven targets" instead of "Execute shell" for the build step did the trick. Took a bit of searching to get to this, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but now I have resolve it.
Now I share the way.

when start docker container of jenkins,please execute follow commandline:

> 「docker run -d -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -v /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_281/:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_281 -v /usr/local/apache-maven-3.6.3/:/usr/local/apache-maven-3.6.3 --name jenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins:lts」

Mapping your local linux environment of jdk and maven to the jenkins container, you can try it.